# Deleting field in elasticsearch

Tags: json, search, elasticsearch

In my elasticsearch, I need to remove a field that has a structure that looks something like this:

```
{"key": 
    {"anotherKey":
               {"firstEntryKey":"firstValue"},
               {"secondEntry":"secondValue"}
      }
}
```

I want to remove the secondEntry from the record, how can that be done?

I've tried using the update api,passing a script, but this does not seem to work:

```
{"script" : 
         "ctx._source.remove("key.anotherKey.secondEntry")
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a nested document?

Comment: I believe the correct teminology is multilevel object, so I know the key and the path to it, but how do I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the document you posted doesn't appear to be legal, I'm assuming you meant this:

```
{
   "key": {
      "anotherKey": {
         "firstEntryKey": "firstValue",
         "secondEntry": "secondValue"
      }
   }
}
```

So if I create an index and post that document,

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index

PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
   "key": {
      "anotherKey": {
         "firstEntryKey": "firstValue",
         "secondEntry": "secondValue"
      }
   }
}

GET /test_index/doc/1
...
{
   "_index": "test_index",
   "_type": "doc",
   "_id": "1",
   "_version": 1,
   "found": true,
   "_source": {
      "key": {
         "anotherKey": {
            "firstEntryKey": "firstValue",
            "secondEntry": "secondValue"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then update the document with the new version, I get back the new version:

```
PUT /test_index/doc/1
{
   "key": {
      "anotherKey": {
         "firstEntryKey": "firstValue"
      }
   }
}

GET /test_index/doc/1
...
{
   "_index": "test_index",
   "_type": "doc",
   "_id": "1",
   "_version": 2,
   "found": true,
   "_source": {
      "key": {
         "anotherKey": {
            "firstEntryKey": "firstValue"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/fb38750594550d4bf7f8a168883a168c7adc3d49

Does this solve your problem? If not, leave a comment and I'll try to help further.

Comment: Thanks, that is a valid solution, however I was trying to use the update api, and I found out that the correct syntax to use a script was like this: { "script" : "ctx._source.key.anotherKey.remove('secondEntry')"}. I was using uuids for keys, but had to remove all dashes and make sure that it didn't start with a number to make it work.